# Numpy load.txt does not convert value to integer

Tags: python, numpy

If I run the following code on a windows laptop with numpy 1.16.2, it works. However, when I run this code on a mac with numpy 1.16.4 or 1.16.2, it doesn't and gives the following error:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: '34.623659...'

We have tried installing different versions of numpy on the mac device, however, the same thing happens. Changing int to float works, however, we would like to display the values in integer form.

The command we are using:

```
A = np.loadtxt('ex2data1.txt', delimiter=',', dtype ='int', max_rows = 5)
print(A)
```

With the first lines of the text file being:

```
34.62365962451697,78.0246928153624,0
30.28671076822607,43.89499752400101,0
35.84740876993872,72.90219802708364,0
60.18259938620976,86.30855209546826,1
79.0327360507101,75.3443764369103,1
45.08327747668339,56.3163717815305,0
61.10666453684766,96.51142588489624,1
75.02474556738889,46.55401354116538,1
76.09878670226257,87.42056971926803,1
84.43281996120035,43.53339331072109,1
95.86155507093572,38.22527805795094,0
75.01365838958247,30.60326323428011,0
82.30705337399482,76.48196330235604,1
69.36458875970939,97.71869196188608,1
39.53833914367223,76.03681085115882,0
53.9710521485623,89.20735013750205,1
```

We expected it to return an array with the same values as in the text file but in integer form, however, we receive the error above.

Comment: Strange that it works on Windows but not on a Mac.  Can anyone else confirm that the use of `loadtxt` shown above, with `dtype='int'`, works on Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `float`:

```
A = np.loadtxt('ex2data1.txt', delimiter=',', dtype =float, max_rows = 5).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. However, how could the difference between the two devices be explained?

Comment: @JanvanderHoef Because in, the txt, there are `float`, and the `dtype` is being the type to be converted, however, `int('1.2')` (for example) gives an error, when `int(float('1.2'))` doesn't, please accept my answer if it works

Comment: Outside of the command np.loadtxt it works, putting this into the command, it gives the same error.

Comment: @JanvanderHoef First of all, please accept my answer

Comment: Back to the question. What could be the reason for the difference between devices?

Comment: @JanvanderHoef See [my comment 10 minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56456721/numpy-load-txt-does-not-convert-value-to-integer/56456769?noredirect=1#comment99505720_56456769)

Comment: I don't see how that explains the difference?

Comment: @JanvanderHoef The code that doesn't work is not working because you can't convert a string with a `float` value into an `int`eger, python won't accept it because the `.` (dot) is in the string, whereas converting to `float` works since dot is needed in `float`s, after you do so, it will be a `float` which you can convert to an `int`eger, `int`eger conversion from `float` it's basically rounding down, so `int(1.9)` will return `1` but not `2`, but if you want `2`, do `round(1.9)`, which gives `2`,in `numpy` do: `A = np.loadtxt('ex2data1.txt', delimiter=',', dtype =float, max_rows = 5).round()`

Comment: @JanvanderHoef Could you please accept my answer again?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Accepted your answer.